# Request is not loading in java

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, google-chrome, postman

I am using java + hibernate + mssql + tomcat

I wrote a get service for fetch the records from mssql. The return A table have OneToMany relation with B Table. I gave the fetchtype is EAGER.

I used postman for hit the service url that returns in run on server mode:

> Could not get any response

In debug mode the service is loading with more time. Finally the server is stopped automatically.

After that I used chrome browser I could get the records but not fully. I am getting below error:

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have circular reference in your entities. Introduced by

> A table have OneToMany relation with B Table

Making your application run into endless loop while rendering response, thus eventually, runing out of RAM.

You need additional configuration that depends on what you use to serialize your entities.